# Core Data: Reset to the initial state

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

I have an object, I make some changes to it, but I don't want to save them, I want the 'old' values.

I've tried with:

```
[managedObjectContext rollback];
[managedObjectContext redo];
[managedObjectContext reset];
```

and none of them seems to work ...

```
NSLog(@"current: %@",ingredient.name); // ===> bread
[ingredient setName:@"test new data"];
NSLog(@"new: %@",ingredient.name); // ===> test new data

[managedObjectContext rollback];
[managedObjectContext redo];
[managedObjectContext reset];

NSLog(@"current: %@",ingredient.name); // ===> test new data

// I want again ===> bread
```

Should I refetch the object again ?

thanks,

r.

Comment: yes, see the Accepted Answer from Marcus S.Zarra

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wrap your changes in a `NSUndoManager beginUndoGrouping` and then a `NSUndoManager endUndoGrouping` followed by a `NSUndoManager undo`.

That is the correct way to roll back changes.  The `NSManagedObjectContext` has its own internal `NSUndoManager` that you can access.

### Update showing example

Because the `NSUndoManager` is nil by default on Cocoa Touch, you have to create one **and set it into the `NSManagedObjectContext first`**.

```
//Do this once per MOC
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
[moc setUndoManager:undoManager];
[undoManager release], undoManager = nil;

//Example of a grouped undo
undoManager = [moc undoManager];
NSManagedObject *test = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
[test setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%s Name after set: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [test valueForKey:@"name"]);
[undoManager endUndoGrouping];
[undoManager undo];
NSLog(@"%s Name after undo: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [test valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Also make sure that your accessors are following the rules of KVO and posting `-willChange:`, `-didChange:`, `-willAccess:` and `-DidAccess:` notifications.  If you are just using `@dynamic` accessors then you will be fine.

Comment: It's not working with your suggestion, sure I'm doing something wrong ...

    undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
    [undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
 
    NSLog(@"current: %@",ingredient.name);
    [ingredient setName:@"test new data"];

    NSLog(@"new: %@",ingredient.name);

    [undoManager endUndoGrouping];
    [undoManager undo];

    NSLog(@"current: %@",ingredient.name);

thanks,

r.

Comment: Also, using the NSUndo from the NSManagedObjectModel ingredient, still doesn't work ...

thanks,

r.

Comment: ok, thanks!

the key was:

    [[ingredient managedObjectContext] setUndoManager:undoManager];

Comment: Not to be OCD but you should be autoreleasing the undo manager.

Comment: I see from apple docs why reset didn't work: it clears out the managed objects so ur not even meant to keep references. But why not rollback? Isn't it made for this?

Comment: It can be used yes.  But it is kind of a nuke from orbit type approach :)

Comment: hi Marcus, can we revert back the changes after saving a managed object context?

Comment: No, once the changes are saved from the context that context clears the undo stack that it has reference to.

Comment: So if a UIManagedDocument auto-save kicks in you're screwed? For instance if you want to revert changes made in a child context when the user taps cancel instead of save?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Depends on how you are configured on top of the UIManagedDocument.  If you have a child MOC, for example, then you control the save on that child MOC.  If you are working strictly with the MOC inside of the UIManagedDocument then yes that is a risk.

Comment: Okay, but since I get two contexts from the UIManagedDocument from start of which one is a child context, and since that child context actually gets saved automatically I just assumed the auto-save operation propagated down the tree of contexts. That's not how it works then?

Comment: First, never touch the private context in a UIManagedDocument. Per the spec that is private. Second, the saves propagate up to the private context but not down to any children of the exposed context.

Answer (score 4):

As per Apple's documentation

Using

```
- (void)rollback; 
[managedObjectContext rollback];
```

Removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and deletions, and restores updated objects to their last committed values.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/rollback)

Answer (score 3):

Try `[managedObjectContext refreshObject:ingredient mergeChanges:NO]` prior to the second `NSLog` call.