# CoreData save/revert unsaved changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have a list of objects in a `UITableView`, managed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. When the user selects an object, an edit view is displayed, allowing the user to edit the selected `NSManagedObject` instance. The properties of the object are updated in the object as the user makes changes.

The thing is, there is, as usual, a Save button and a Cancel button. If the user taps save, the `NSManagedObjectContext` is saved, and the change is reflected. However, if the user taps cancel, I need the object to revert to the state it was in before. Calling `[managedObjectContext rollback]` doesn't work for this purpose.

Does anyone know how to properly implement this? I can not store the object's properties as temporary separate ivars during editing, because there are multiple objects that could be edited, all of which have different properties.

#### Update

What I'm currently doing is storing the `NSManagedObject` in an instance variable, and calling `save:` to save and `rollback` to cancel. Instance variables are modified using either `object.property = something` or `[object setValue:something forKey:@"property"]`. This does *not* work as expected, instead producing this behaviour:

1. If you edit and save, changes update as expected. However, if you edit again, and cancel without making changes, the state of the object reverts back as it was *before* the save.
2. If you edit and cancel, the changes are still updated, as if saved. Editing and cancelling again (without making changes) will revert it back to the state it was in before.

#### Also:

Could this have anything to do with the way I initialise the `NSFetchedResultsController` that is used to populate the table view? Code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSString *entityName = self.entityName;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214343/core-data-reset-to-the-initial-state

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked over basically every coredata question here on SO, but somehow managed to miss that one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having given up on all the mechanisms in place in `CoreData` to do this (none of them worked), I ended up storing all the properties of the object as separate variables in the edit view controller, and rolling back to them on cancel.

Answer (score 5):

Look http://www.section42.de/coredata-how-to-revert-a-managed-object-to-its-original-state. This will help you for sure.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you're setting an `NSUndoManager` instance on your managed object context as it is nil by default on iOS. Related solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2214982/318456

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It happened because the `textField` was in modification process when user click back. If user click done on keyboard before click back then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the NSManagedObject as a property of the edit view controller. Then you can edit all of its properties, and either save or rollback when dismissing the view.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. _Exactly_. And it's not working.
Problematic Scenarios:

1. Edit, save, then edit and cancel. Reverts to state __before__ the first save.  

2. Edit and cancel. Changes end up saved. Have to edit and cancel again to fix.